# Python:Find if all elements in lists are the same except exactly 2 numbers

Tags: python, list, numbers, int

I wonder how to check if two lists of numbers are the same except exactly 2 numbers

```
if list1 == list2: # + except 2 numbers
```

Comment: What do you mean "except two numbers"? The lists only vary by two?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: for example, it will be true if first list will have 1,2,3,4,5 and the second 1,2,3,6,7

Comment: You can try this: `result = len([i for i in list1 if i not in list2]) == 2`

Comment: Can `list1` and `list2` contain duplicates?

Comment: @Helium_1s2 Yes

Comment: @teddy Just to make sure I understand correctly, the result for `list1 = [1,1,2,3,3]` and `list2=[1,2,2,2,3]` should be `True`, right?

Comment: @Helium_1s2 Right, correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order of list elements is important, you can use something like this:

```
if sum(i != j for i, j in zip(list1, list2)) == 2:
    # the two lists are equal except two elements
```

If order is not important, and repeated elements do not matter, you could also use set intersection (`&`) and compare length:

```
if len(set(list1) & set(list2)) == len(list1) - 2:
    # the two list are equal except two elements
```

If order is not important, but repeated elements matter, use the same approach, but with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
if len(Counter(list1) & Counter(list2)) == len(list1) - 2:
    # the two list are equal except two elements
```

Comment: You could also use set union, although I'm not sure if it would be any faster.`if len(set(list1) | set(list2)) == len(list1) + 2:`

Comment: Actually, the solutions using set would not work, since OP clarified that there can be repeated elements. You would have to use something like C++'s multiset, but I don't think Python has that by default.

Comment: @Helium_1s2 python's multiset is [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), however OP hasn't clarified if order is important or not

Comment: op has clarified that there can be repeated elements, so regular sets won't work in those cases. I'm saying you need to use a multiset for the case where order is not important.

Comment: @Helium_1s2 yes, I agree. I just wanted to point out that in either case (set or Counter) the order of elements would be disregarded.

Answer (score 2):

```
def differ_by_two(l1, l2):
    return sum(1 for i,j in zip(l1, l2) if i!=j) == 2
```

Example

```
>>> differ_by_two([1,2,3],[1,4,5])
True
>>> differ_by_two([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10])
False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def SameBarTwo(l1, l2):
    a = len(l2)
    for i in range(len(l2)):
        if l2[i] in l1:
            l1.remove(l2[i])
            a -= 1
    return a == 2
```

This will make accommodations for duplicate values, order is not taken into account.